# Reverse for 'account' not found. 'account' is not a valid view function or pattern name.121

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPzWj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5FeA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE2im.png)

Hello, can you help me? Django gives me this error. Reverse for 'account' not found. 'account' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Inside the photo is a complete explanation

Comment: Did you add the reference to your `main.urls` module at `webSite.urls`?

Comment: A more descriptive link to the images could help you get more answers, but even better are inline images. So the reader will not have to click on each of your links.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refer to the app_name from your account.urls instead of 'main', and then use the name value of the corresponding url route. Reverse referencing for urls works for individual urls, not for the script. '<app_name>:<route_name>' - always use this format.